# Asymptotic $T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+1$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I would like to find the complexity of $T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+1$

I did :
$$T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+1$$
$$T(n)=T(n^{1/2})+1$$
$$T(n)=(T(n^{1/4})+1)+1=T(n^{1/4})+2$$
And after $k$ steps :
$$T(n)=T(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}})+k$$

How should I continue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n=m^{2^k}$, then
$$
T(m^{2^{k+1}})=T(m^{2^k})+1
$$
and if $S_m(k)=T(m^{2^k})$, then $S_m(k)=k+S_m(0)$.

Hence
$$
T(n)=\log_2(\log n)+c.
$$